# How can I find webpages with webapps using a specific framework?

Tags: web-application, java

How can I find webpages using webapps using a specific framework, like you can look for apache servers with shodan.
In my case the application are made with java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117131/how-to-find-out-what-programming-language-a-website-is-built-in). Also, take a look [here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151472/is-it-possible-to-know-what-programming-language-a-web-site-uses) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396739/how-do-you-determine-what-technology-a-website-is-built-on).

Comment: @MiaoHatola Those questions are about identifying the framework used by a single website. This question is about finding all/many websites which use a specific framework.

Comment: @tim You are right. My bad.  Maybe the OP can try to automate these huristics.

Comment: I don't see how this question is considered to be off-topic for this site. Considering for example a new vulnerability is discovered (in a framework), this question asks for a way to check how many websites are vulnerable (since they are using the framework). Which is security related

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can get an idea what technology a particular site uses. Among them are:

- observing file extensions in URLs
- technologies mentioned in job postings
- tech blog articles
- company's open-source work
- header leaks

So build a list of candidate sites and then go inspect them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use google (or any search engine of your choice).

Most frameworks or languages contain specific identifying characteristics:

- "powered by" footer (easy, but unlikely, especially for a language)
- specific error messages, if errors are shown (something containing `java.lang.NullPointerException` for Java; most frameworks also have some specific error messages)
- meta files such as changelogs
- files that are always present such as specific CSS files (use inurl)
- some frameworks and languages set specific HTTP header for which you can search
- ...

Answer (score 0):

You cant. Java is a language, not a framework. There is nothing that can search the backend of peoples compiled code.

Comment: can I find all websites using java applications ?

Comment: No. The code is located on the server, removed from you. You have no insight to that. If you have one particular site, you may be able to find out which language its using if you can get it to throw an error and print a stacktrace or something like that, but there is no universal search for java applications, like shodan, because its not possible.